# Does Redis support split one key into multiple Redis Instances?

Tags: redis

For example, I have one big list in redis, one instance can't hold it. does Redis support to split the list into other instances?

If yes, do i need to do any configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are talking about system memory or the implementation size of a list.

**Redis List**

> The max length of a list is 232 - 1 elements (4294967295, more than 4 billion of elements per list).

Do you need more than 4 billion elements? For a string with 10 bytes that's at least 40GB in one list just in string storage, not counting any list extra implementation overhead.

**Memory**

If you have space on the list but there's not enough memory then:

> If Redis can't remove keys according to the policy, or if the policy is
>    set to `noeviction`, Redis will start to reply with errors to commands
>    that would use more memory, like SET, LPUSH, and so on, and will continue
>    to reply to read-only commands like GET - *in [redis.conf 2.8](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/2.8/redis.conf)*

Does this clarify your questions on the matter ?

Comment: Thanks @bitoiu, it clarified my questions.